# How to accumulate over each number? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, max, min

This is my problem I am having a hard time onto what to do to solve this
The Task: We'll pass you an array of two numbers.
Return the sum of those two numbers plus the
sum of all the numbers between them. The lowest number will not always come first.

```
For example, sumAll([4,1]) should return 10 because
sum of all the numbers between 1 and 4 (both inclusive) is 10.
```

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  Math.min(arr); //finds the lowest number and takes it 1
  Math.max(arr); //finds the largest number 4
  //must start at the 1st number and loops over until the max value is reached
  //0 start at the 0th index of the array 
  //++ increament by one so 1 2 3 4 
  //multiply's each number
  //.lenght until the lenght of the array is reached
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    i * i;
  }
  return 1;
}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Comment: Is it going to be always 2 numbers in an array?

Comment: Everyone is using loops when this can be done O(1)... `function sum(arr) { const start = arr[0], end = arr[1]; return (end - start + 1) * (start + end) / 2; }`

Comment: @D.Pardal Add an answer, but make sure to sort first

Comment: @segFault I was about to do it, but then the question got closed...

Answer (score 2):

If its going to be always 2 numbers in an array, then you can easily do this and no more fancy code.

```
var arr = [1, 4];
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var total = 0;
for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++ ) {
     total += i;
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: It is not necessary the first index would be lowest, that's the main question.

Comment: I see, I haven't notifice that, then he can just sort it first. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the largest number from your input array using `Math.max` and the smallest number from the array using `Math.min`, you just need to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the values from the array into the method calls so that the numbers from the input array are used as the arguments (rather than the array itself).

Once you have the largest and smallest number, you can find the sum between (and including) these two numbers. This can be done using a loop. However, a more efficient way would be to use a formula to compute it for you. If you call the smaller number `a` and the larger number `b`, you want to find:

```
res     = a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + (b-1) + b
res2    = b + (b-1) + (b-2) + ... + (a+1) + a
```

As you can see above `res2` and `res` are equal. So we can say `res2 = res`. So, if we perform `res + res2`, we will get `2*res`. If we add the two together (adding by the columns), we get:

```
2*res = a+b + (a+1)+(b-1) + (a+2)+(b-2) + ... + (b-1)+(a+1) + b+a
      = a+b +     a+b     +     a+b     + ... +     a+b     + a+b
```

As you can see `2*res` results in `a+b` being repeated for every number in the original equation, which is `b-a + 1` times. Thus:

```
2*res = (b-a + 1)*(a+b)
```

As we want to find what `res` is, we can divide both sides by `2` to get:

```
res = (b-a + 1)*(a+b)/2
```

So, we can use the above equation to find the sum of numbers between two numbers `a` and `b`, where `a` is the smaller number and `b` is the larger number.

Using both `Math.max()`, `Math.min()` and the above equation, we can do this using the following:

```js
const sumRange = (a, b) => ((b - a + 1)*(a + b))/2;
function sumAll(arr) {
  const smaller = Math.min(...arr);
  const bigger = Math.max(...arr);
  return sumRange(smaller, bigger); 
}

console.log(sumAll([4, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways, in this case I am using a while loop.

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  // Get the min/max values from the array,
  // Note: you have to spread the array values as individual args using '...' notation
  const min = Math.min(...arr);
  const max = Math.max(...arr); 
  
  // Start at the min value
  let current = min;
  let sum = 0;
  // Loop through all numbers between min and max inclusively
  while (current <= max) {
    sum += current;
    current++;
  }
  
  return sum;
};

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just find the lower number before running the loop for getting the sum of all inbetween numbers.

You can just add the condition:

```
    if(arr[0]<arr[1]){
     first= arr[0], last= arr[1]
     }
   else { 
    first=arr[1], last=arr[0] }
  for (i = first; i <= last; i++){
     let temp = temp + i;
    }
   return temp;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just sort the array and run the loop to add the number , starting from first element ending at second element

```js
function findSum(arr){
    let sortedArr = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => a-b);
    let total =0;
    for(let i=arr[0];i<=arr[1];i++){
        total+=i;
}
console.log(total);
}

findSum([1,4])
```

Comment: Can the person , who downvoted solution, specify the reason too ? It is much needed to understand the issue. Unnecessary downvotes are discourged!

Answer (score -1):

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10]; 
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
points[0]; // this is min value of the array values
```

[You can check this link on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_sort_low)